# Angular orderBy evaluate expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like my orderBy to evaluate an expression

Currently I have:

```
ng_repeat: "post in posts | orderBy:"up_votes"
```

I would like it instead to order by {{up_votes - down_votes}}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ng_repeat: "post in posts | orderBy:'down_votes - up_votes'"
```

Just use single quotes to wrap the expression for orderBy

Or you could add a voteDiff function to the controller and do `orderBy:voteDiff`